# MarkupLM model applied to html longer than 512

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

I’m using markupLM transformer for token classsification with finance articles longer than 512 max length i’m asking if there is a solution to fine tune MarkupLM with inputs longer than 512 .

I was trying to chunk tensors but this method increase information loss i'm looking for another solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sliding window technique, where you break up the input text into overlapping segments or chunks and feed each chunk through the model separately.

Example below:

```
tokens = tokenizer.encode(input_text, add_special_tokens=False)
start = 0
end = min(window_size, len(tokens))
chunks = []
while start < len(tokens):
    chunks.append(tokens[start:end])
    if end == len(tokens):
        break
    start = end - overlap_size
    end = min(start + window_size, len(tokens))

results = []
for chunk in chunks:
    input_ids = tokenizer.build_inputs_with_special_tokens(chunk)
    input_ids = torch.tensor(input_ids).unsqueeze(0)
    outputs = model(input_ids)
    predictions = outputs.logits.argmax(-1).squeeze().tolist()
    results.extend(predictions)
```

Comment: feeding the model with each chunk through the model separately does not affect predictions ? and for markupLM model each input is composed of input ids and xpath subs and tags sequence (markupLM is based on html codes ) so how to deal with this xpath tokens ?

Comment: Feeding the model with each chunks may indeed affect prediction. Depends on the problem and the data being used. It general it does affect it. 

Regarding the xpath tokens in MarkupLM, you may need to split them up along with the text input into smaller chunks and feed them through the model separately.

Comment: If the answer helped can you accept it please ?